# Flutter: Transparent appbar is hiding content

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a transparent app bar that hides some of my content, because the content starts behind the app bar:

[image: appbar hides content]

My `Scaffold` looks like this:

```
return Scaffold(
  extendBody: true,
  extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
  appBar: getAppBar(),
  body: generateMainBody(context),
);
```

If I would set `extendBodyBehindAppBar` to false it would work, however, the appbar would not be transparent anymore (when scrolling the area that is not part of that cool shape would be black and not transparent like in the screenshot).

I thought of adding some top padding to just move the cut content down a little bit but surely there has to be a better solution?

Comment: Don't know off the top of my head of any other way but adding top padding to compensate for the app bar's height, so it can go underneath it, so yeah in my opinion that's the only way for now, unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: Yeah, prolly padding.  Nice effect!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the only solution seems to be some kind of padding I settled with this:

`SizedBox(height: MainAppBar.appBarHeight)`

I simply added an empty `SizedBox` that has the height of the `AppBar` to the top of my content.

Answer (score 1):

In your generateMainBody function, wrap your current return with padding and change the padding  `padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),`. You can increase or decrease the '8.0' to best suit your app.